# Difficulties to understand projections (about PCA)

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

About PCA I read that we were looking for the direction $w_1 \in \mathbb{R^p}$ with $||w||=1$ such that the variance of our data projected onto this direction is maximal. The word "projection" makes me confused

For example imagine we have a matrix $M_{4,3}(\mathbb{R})$ like $X = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2}\\ 
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2}\\ 
a_{3,1} & a_{3,2}\\ 
a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} 
\end{bmatrix}$ (variables in columns)

Once the PCA is done, I take the eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue, say $w_1 \in \mathbb{R^{2}}$ and if I want to project for example $ v=[a_{1,1}, a_{1,2}]$ on the base $w_1$ I have to do the dot product between $v$ and $w_1$ right?

But for me intuitively if I want to project on the vector $w_1$ I have to do $(v \cdot w_1)*w_1$ (multiply the result of the dot product by $w_1$. I know it's false, but it makes me confused about the projections.

If take a simpler example the canonical $u = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$ and for example $v =  \begin{bmatrix}
2, 3\\
\end{bmatrix}$.
What is the exact and intuitive difference between: $v\cdot u$ and $(v\cdot u)*u$
(except that one is length and the other the length multiply by the vector)

Thanks for your help

Comment: First of all, please try to make your question a bit easier to read. At the very least, clarify what you mean by "multiply by (w1/||w1)". What does (w1/||w1) mean? Do you mean $w_1/|w_1|$?

Comment: To answer your main question, it doesn't make sense for the projection of $X$ onto $w$ to be a single scalar value: the matrix $X$ consists of multiple data points (i.e. columns), and each of these columns gets a scalar corresponding to its projection onto $w_1$.

Comment: yes exactly, but why the dot product between w1 and X are projections? don't we have to multiply by the w vector at the end?

Comment: It is hard to understand why you're saying "yes exactly" given your comment "But I thought that the projection of the data z1 is rather : z1=((w1.⊤) @ X)*w1 ?"

Comment: To answer your latest comment, the dot product between $w_1$ and a column of $X$ is the [scalar projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_projection) of this column onto $w_1$. We could recover the corresponding [vector projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection), if we want, by multiplying by $w_1$. However, for most applications of PCA, it is common to work with the scalar projections instead.

Comment: Disregard my third comment; I was confused about the "Pythonic" expression `z1=((w1.⊤) @ X)*w1 ` which corresponds to the mathematical $w_1w_1^TX$ (as opposed to the scalar $w_1^TXw_1$).

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear but you still understood what I meant. So yes my question now is rather why are we using scalar projection instead of vector projection ?

Comment: Glad we're on the same page. So the obvious part of the answer to your question is that it's computationally easier/faster to work with scalar projections since that means we only need 1 (or in general, only however principal components you choose) number (or numbers) per data point. The less obvious part is that **it is possible** to do whatever it is that you're trying to do using the vector projection using only the scalar projection. In order to show that this is true, I need to know what you're trying to do that you think requires the full vector projection...

Comment: ...So, please edit your question with some details about what you're trying to use PCA for. In particular, is there a reason you believe that you should be working with the full vector projection instead?

Comment: Is it better? :)

Comment: Definitely better, but not quite what I was asking for. Again, is there a reason that you think using the full vector projection, other than the fact that this is what you intuitively think of as a "projection"? Is there something that's easier to do or see for you using the vector projection than it would be using the scalar projection?

Comment: For me, the "exact and intuitive difference between: $v\cdot u$ and $(v\cdot u)*u$" is **only** that the first (a scalar) is the length of the second. So the answer to your second of two explicit questions, "What is the exact and intuitive difference between: $v\cdot u$ and $(v\cdot u)*u$ 
(except that one is length and the other the length multiply by the vector)", is "nothing". The answer to the first of the two explicit questions, "if I want to project for example $ v=[a_{1,1}, a_{1,2}]$ on the base $w_1$ I have to do the dot product between $v$ and $w_1$ right?", is "Right".

Comment: Actually there is no reason why I'm thinking about full vector projection. It's just that for me "projection" return vector and not scalar. I'm a just a simple software engineer who want to fully understand the PCA just for curiosity and it's been 2 days since I've been trying to convince myself that by projection we can also talk about scalar :).

Comment: So if I understood, depending on the context I can use the scalar or the vector projection? And here for the PCA, in order to facilitate the calculations we focus on the scalar projection?

Comment: You can get proper double norm bars by using `\|` instead of `||`.